# An object (a view model) transferred among action results within the same controller turns into either string or null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a view model and some other data from one controller action method to another action method within the same controller. The parameter-argument pair needs to handle various view models. For this effect, I store the view model object and other data in an object.

```
public class infViewModel
{
   //Fields...
}

public class infElement
{
   public Guid ID { get; set; }
   public object ViewModel { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult actionOne(infViewModel pCurrentViewModel)
{
   infViewModel _CurrentViewModel = new infViewModel();
   _CurrentViewModel = pCurrentViewModel;

   infElement _Element = new infElement();
   _Element.ViewModel = _CurrentViewModel;

   return RedirectToAction(“actionTwo”, _Element);
}

public ActionResult actionTwo(infElement pElement)
{
}
```

I can pass data of different types, such as `string` and `Guid`, but fail in passing the object that contains the view model.

I observe loss of data somewhere between the argument and the parameter:
`QuickWatch` of the argument object `_Element` shows the intended data intact, including the `_Element.ViewModel` object along with the fields of the ViewModel and the fields’ respective contents.

On the other hand, `QuickWatch` of the parameter object `pElement` shows that the `pElement.ViewModel` object turned into a plain string. The string is a concatenation of the name space, class, etc. In the same time, the other data, such as `pElement.ID`, appears intact.

I made `infElement` generic:

```
public class infElement<T>
{
   public Guid ID { get; set; }
   public T ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

but the result was essentially the same, except that now `pElement.ViewModel` is `null`.

How should I transfer the view model among action results?

Comment: How many web servers are you running on? Do you have session state enabled?

Comment: Question: Do you really need `RedirectToAction`? About the only reasons for using it are to change the URL in the user's browser or perhaps to force the browser to read a cookie you just wrote. Keep in mind, `RedirectToAction` doesn't go directly to the action method, it sends HTTP 302 to the browser instructing it to come back to your `actionTwo` method, so your server-side state will be lost in the round trip unless you store it somewhere.

Comment: @mjwills, I'm running a single server (so far). Yes, I am using server side persistence with session. Actually, that is the role of `actionTwo`. It is an action method inherited by several controllers from a base controller. All derived controllers must be able to hand over their unique view models, so that I'll have a single-point-of-maintenance for the logic that persists the view model (in session) for the use of certain other controllers in certain conditions.

Comment: @NightOwl888 . I was not aware of the round trip with the browser being involved. I'll do some reading... So, given my intention, as I specified in my response to the comment of mjwills (please see above), how would you suggest me to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where `TempData` is appropriate:

```
public ActionResult actionOne(infViewModel pCurrentViewModel)
{
   infViewModel _CurrentViewModel = new infViewModel();
   _CurrentViewModel = pCurrentViewModel;

   infElement _Element = new infElement();
   _Element.ViewModel = _CurrentViewModel;

   TempData["_Element"] = _Element;

   return RedirectToAction("actionTwo");
}

public ActionResult actionTwo()
{
    var _Element = TempData["_Element"] as infElement;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `TempData` did the trick. A solution becomes really useful when I understand why my code didn't work, and it seems that @NightOwl888 explained the mechanism of the problem. Now I'll try to find a solution that will not only work, but will also stick to the good ol' data coupling provided by arguments and parameters, as I tried in the first place.